# HTML5, Jquery Mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

i am using html5 and jquerymobile framework 1.1 for creating this app.
i need to pop up mobile keypad when click on the orange button next input box

can any one let me know how to fix this?

```
<div class="field-container">
    <div class="dataarealeft">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Monthly Income</div>
        <div class="dataarearight">
         <input data-theme="c"  type="number" min="500" max="10000" name="monthly-income" id="monthly-income" value=""  >
                     <img src="css/images/orangekey.png"/></input>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give focus to the input box as you "click" the image would that suffice?